# Headers in QtCore not found when reactivating old project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am trying to get an old qt-project running again. I believe that it has been written in QT4.x and I am using QT 5.5 now.

The *.pro file looks somewhat like this:

```
######################################################################
# Automatically generated by qmake (2.01a) Di 29. Okt 15:17:13 2013
######################################################################

TEMPLATE = app TARGET =  DEPENDPATH += . INCLUDEPATH += .

# Input 
HEADERS += ****all *.h files of the project are listed here****
FORMS += mainform.ui 
SOURCES += ***all *.cpp files of the project are listed here****
```

The listed issues after building[image] are:

So, It can't find many header-files that are part of QT! I have tried

```
QT       += core gui
CONFIG   += qt
```

which did not help. I know believe that it has to do with the migration from QT4 to Qt5. In this [link](https://wiki.qt.io/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5) it sounds like there has been some reorganization. Maybe I just need to change "#include < Qt/QString.h >" into something new?

Comment: maybe simply <QString> would work?

Comment: Usually it needs to simple `#include <QString>` in both Qt4 and Qt5

Comment: Have a read of this article: https://wiki.qt.io/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5 there are a lot of thing to take care when upgrading your project from v.4 to v.5 (that's why the transition is so slow: Qt 5 was released in 2012)

Comment: The #include <QString> worked. The weird thing is, that Qtcreator for example suggests  "<QtWidgets>", but if I choose it and compile, I get the error "QtWidgets: No such file or directory". How can that be? QtWidgets is not the only case where that happens (same for example with pcl/common/common.h).

Answer (score 1):

Please first modify your .pro file to some thing as follows:

```
QT       += core gui multimedia

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = <Your Target Name>
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += static

HEADERS *= ../Include/*.h

SOURCES *= ../Source/*.cpp \
#Add this line if you have any .ui files to add
FORMS *= ../Forms/*.ui \
```

From Qt5 onwards, Qt treats every thing as Qwidget. Probably due to that reason you are getting the above error which you have highlighted in blue.

for strings you just use #include "qstring.h" and then you can check.

Hope that Helps.

Comment: "From Qt5 onwards, Qt treats every thing as Qwidget" => No

Comment: Can you please share any URL with respect to that? Because I understand it treats every thing as qWidgets.

Comment: QtWidgets is separated from QtGui, that's all (http://wiki.qt.io/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5)